# React native - how to ignore silent mode and play sound/send push notification?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'd like to make an app with React Native that lets you chat with your significant other, and totally ignores silent mode. I.e., even if your phone is in silent mode, this app will still play sounds to alert you of new messages and send you push notifications. The idea is that you can put your phone on silent to block messages from friends, coworkers, etc, but your significant other can still message you and you can hear when they and only they send you a message.

How can you do this on React Native? I'm assuming that this is possible (at the very least on iOS) as the Apple Watch is able to make your phone peep even if it's on silent (unless this is a top secret feature that only Apple developers are allowed to use).

Comment: hi, any solution found for this?

Comment: Any solution for overriding silent mode with React Native?